# Non-blocking read on Windows named pipes

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

I need to implement non-blocking reading and writing from windows named pipes using Python (ctypes).
I am able to achieve this if the pipe is opened in server mode.
But I fail to do it when opening the pipe with client, using CreateFile.

ReadFile blocks, no matter that the pipe was created with PIPE_NOWAIT by the server process.
I'm trying to use windll.kernel32.SetNamedPipeHandleState on the handle returned by windll.kernel32.CreateFileW, but get an error ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

The description for SetNamedPipeHandleState says that it must have GENERIC_READ and FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access for a read-only pipe.

How do I set these flags when opening a file? And will it actually help to resolve my problem?

Comment: you need use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` option in `CreateFile` (in `dwFlagsAndAttributes`)

Comment: and *Nonblocking mode* != *asynchronous I/O* - this is different things. i suggest use not *Nonblocking mode* but exactly *asynchronous I/O* - so use `PIPE_WAIT` flag in `CreateNamedPipe` and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in both calls to `CreateNamedPipe` and `CreateFile`

Comment: Does that mean using callbacks? This might imply serious changes to my code.

Comment: yes, asynchronous i/o usually use callbacks. or another completion way. this is different from nonblocking io which just return result (success or fail). asynchronous io usual return `STATUS_PENDING` and operation complete some late (with success or fail). if you not want/can do this - you in this case really need `SetNamedPipeHandleState`

Comment: Yes, I really can't change it. So I just need to understand how to set GENERIC_READ and FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES.

Comment: you really need have `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` on file handle. you need set this in call `CreateFile`

Comment: so you need `CreateFile("your pipe name", FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, ..)`

Comment: You could offload onto another thread and use `Queue.read_no_wait` to read, and adapt the technique for writes. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/5240004) for an example. Or you could just use/adapt the [python-nonblock](https://pypi.org/project/python-nonblock/) module from PyPi, which implements async reads and writes in pure python.